# cURL instance not fully captured in a lambda

Tags: c++, curl, lambda

I am trying to send an email in parallel to my main pipeline. 
For that I am pushing a lambda in a concurrent queue that is executing it independently from the main thread.

I am using cURL to send this email. Everything works fine unless I capture the curl instance in the lambda.

This is how I proceed:

```
  auto str = FormatEmail(event); // Format the URL
  auto handle_copy = curl_easy_duphandle(curl_.get()); // copy of the handle

  job::Post([=]() {
    if (!handle_copy) throw std::runtime_error("cURL handle not valid.");

    std::stringstream payload;
    payload << str;

    curl_easy_setopt(handle_copy, CURLOPT_READDATA, &payload);

    FILE* logfile;
    logfile = fopen("dump.txt", "wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(handle_copy, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle_copy, CURLOPT_STDERR, logfile);

    CURLcode result;
    result = curl_easy_perform(handle_copy);
    std::cerr << result;
    if (result == CURLE_OK) log_.Debug("Email sent successfully: %0%.", log.str());

    curl_easy_cleanup(handle_copy);
    fclose(logfile);
  });
```

I am formatting the email outside of the lambda, but I could do it inside as well ... The only issue is that the dump I am producing is the following:

> - Rebuilt URL to: smtp://aspmx.l.google.com:25/
> - Trying 74.125.71.27...
> - Connected to aspmx.l.google.com (74.125.71.27) port 25 (#0) < 220 mx.google.com ESMTP a78si8197651wme.159 - gsmtp
>
>   EHLO cgross-H81M-DS2V < 250-mx.google.com at your service,
>     [77.95.183.158]
>
>   250-SIZE 157286400
>
>   250-8BITMIME
>
>   250-STARTTLS
>
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>
>   250-PIPELINING
>
>   250-CHUNKING
>
>   250 SMTPUTF8
>
>   MAIL FROM: < 250 2.1.0 OK a78si8197651wme.159 -
>     gsmtp
>
>   RCPT TO:< > < 553 5.1.2 The recipient address < > is not a valid
>     RFC-5321 address. a78si8197651wme.159 - gsmtp
> - RCPT failed: 553
>
>   QUIT < 221 2.0.0 closing connection a78si8197651wme.159 - gsmtp
> - Closing connection 0

It just seems that not all the data is captured in the copy of my handle ... How could I proceed to execute the sending (/Formatting as well ideally) in parallel for curl?

Comment: Where are you setting `CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM` option? Also see if `payload` (when inside lambda on different thred) contains what you expect it to contain.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin sorry for the extremely late reply. CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM is set in the ctor of my initial object, so totally outside of the thread. and you're right, the payload doesnt have what it should have when its put in the thread ...

Comment: Oh, here you go. So it probably has nothing to do with cURL, you just need to find out why you are not getting right payload. My guess is `FormatEmail` returns some type which retains some shared state when copied.